# Use of 'think ' and 'reckon'

Tags: sentence-construction

-I think he is right.
-I reckon he is right.

Which one of the above sentences is more accurate  and why?

Answer (score 1):

Both carry the same meaning, so neither is more **accurate** than the other. However "reckon " in this sense is a regionalism, mostly from the US South, Midwest and West, and particularly outside thre South, dating from the 1800s. It is now common only in historical fiction, or in the speech of isolated communities, such as some in Appalachia, that have preserved older usages.

"Reckon" previously meant "calculate" and is still sometimes used in that sense, particularly in the phrasal verb "reckon up"

Comment: I reckon I've heard "I reckon..." being used by modern British speakers, and it doesn't seem like a Britishism to me.

Comment: @JamesK - In Britain, 'reckon' (meaning 'think' or 'be of the opinion') can be an informal alternative, especially in conversation, to the more standard 'think', especially in London and the South East.

Comment: @JamesK - Agreed, but it's more informal than "I think".